# None after end of for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a for loop using Python and one example is implementing a substring function similar to `slice()` . When I run the program, I get a `None` after the stop index and I don't want it. It should say `ell`

```
def substring(start,stop,s): # where s is the string on which the method is invoked
    for i in s[start:stop+1]: # starting and stopping indices
        print(i,end="")

print(substring(1,3,'Hello'))
#output = ellNone
```

Comment: Remove the `print` statement around the substring function

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything, so why are you printing its return value?

Comment: Not sur what's your logic here. But if just want the string slicing, you can change and put this line (only) in function body:  ` return s[start:start+stop] `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `print`inside a function, you don't need the outside one .It prints `None` because the function do not return a value.
So, you have to remove the last print statement to avoid it.

`substring(1,3,'Hello')`

Comment: Yeah just realized that this method prints the result already. ‍♂️